# Windows Forms Anchors, Keep controls inside panel at the same ratio?

Tags: c#, resize, anchor, picturebox, dock

I have this Panel with 2 PictureBoxs inside, they are both Anchored too all edges of the screen:

[image: Before Resize]

This is how it looks on minimum screen size. (Good)

Now this is how it look after i resize the screen to a bigger size:

[image: After Resize]

As you see 1 PictureBox overides another...
I tried lots of kindes of anchros and docks..

but still on resize it's all f***ed up..
How can i keep the ratio between them?

So when the screen get bigger they both get bigger equally and looks like in the first picture but larger?

**C# .NET 3.5 Windows Forms**

UPDATE:

Ok i use `tableLayoutPanel` now it looks like that:

[image]

And after resizing it looks like that:

[image]

You might think it's good, but you can see it didn't preserve the ratio..

And no i dont have a Wide Screen.. i have a 19" Screen on **1280 x 1024**

So why does it heppend?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: You should probably use a SplitContainer for this. Even setting the Anchor property properly for both wouldn't solve this problem.

Comment: On another note, that is a *sweet* loading image. Where did you find that?

Comment: The TableLayoutPanel control was made for this.  One column, two rows at 50% and dock the panels inside.  You could create the gap in between with an absolute row.

Comment: @Evan from [PreLoadres.net](http://www.preloaders.net/)

Comment: @Hans Hey i used it and it almost solved my problem.. can you look at the update please?

Comment: You cannot preserve aspect ratio of course.  There's actually little point in making this form have a resizable border.

Comment: @Hans what do you mean exactly? it's weird that it gets wide on a squere screen.. isn't it ? The original size of the PictureBox is **240, 180**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't bind the bottom panel's Up `Anchor`. But the better way is to use `SplitContainer` or  `TableLayoutPanel` control to split your pannel.

Comment: But i want the panel to stay in the same pos.. if i'm not anchoring him to the Top he gets like Wide Panel...

Comment: As I said before the best way is to using SplitContainer. the first way I said is not good.